# Why dynamic_cast is ok to use for upcast for non polymorphic types?

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism, dynamic-cast

See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/):

> dynamic_cast can only be used with pointers and references to classes
>   (or with void*). Its purpose is to ensure that the result of the type
>   conversion points to a valid complete object of the destination
>   pointer type.
>
> This naturally includes pointer upcast (converting from
>   pointer-to-derived to pointer-to-base), in the same way as allowed as
>   an implicit conversion.
>
> But dynamic_cast can also downcast (convert from pointer-to-base to
>   pointer-to-derived) polymorphic classes (those with virtual members)
>   if -and only if- the pointed object is a valid complete object of the
>   target type.

Why dynamic_cast is ok to use for upcast for non polymorphic types but is not OK for downcast again for non-polymorphic types?

Comment: I don't read, that it's OK to use it for upcasting _**non**-polymorphic_ types.

Comment: Most likely because it needs virtual dispatch to make sure the conversion is good as it returns `null_ptr` if it is not.  Otherwise `[expr.dynamic.cast]` says it has to be polymorphic for down casts.

Comment: But what do you think, why "polymorphic classes" is outlined for downcast only?

Comment: @Narek As I said it probably needs the mechanics the are implemented with polymorphic classes to tell at run time if the conversion is successful.  I don't know if you could do that with a non-polymorphic type.

Comment: Because the standard says so, and it says so because the i tent if dynamic_vast is to perform a **checked-at-runtime** cast, which is only possible if there is something to check against. The only thing to check against is the hidden polymorphism-carrying  data and it only exists in polymorphic classes.

Comment: Also, regarding your edit, up casts should be fine.  The standard even examples non-polymorphic up casting in the `dynamic_cast` section.

Comment: [This](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) is a much better reference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Converting a pointer-to-derived-type into a pointer-to-base-type can be done without knowing anything about the exact type of the object that's being pointed to, because the derived type is always an instance of the base type. That is, the conversion depends only on **static** information. So `dynamic_cast` in that direction is always okay, because it can always be done.

Using `dynamic_cast` to convert the other way requires knowing the actual type of the object being pointed to, because without that information there's no way to know whether the conversion is valid. For example:

```
Base* bp = get_base();
Derived* dp = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(bp);
```

In this situation, if `bp` in fact points to an object of type `Base` the conversion is not valid; if it points to an object of type `Derived` or a type derived from `Derived`, the cast is okay.

To determine the exact type of the object at runtime, the support code relies on embedded type information that is only required to be present for polymorphic types. That's why the base-to-derived cast requires a polymorphic type: it ensures that the required information is present.

Granted, the standard could have made the derived-to-base conversion invalid for non-polymorphic types, but that's a procrustean restriction; there's no good reason for prohibiting it.

Comment: "*there's no good reason for prohibiting it*" I have one: because `static_cast` already covers it. That would mean that `dynamic_cast` could *only* be used for polymorphic base-to-derived conversions. That way, if you see `dynamic_cast` in your codebase, you know what someone is trying to do.

Comment: @NicolBolas - yes, some people like procrustean rules. Others don't.

Comment: Why is dynamic_cast able to look at the dynamic type of a reference/pointer only if the class itself is polymorphic? What's the internal mechanism? Does it involve vtables and stuff like that? @PeteBecker

Comment: @gedamial -- yes, that information is usually related to the vtable. But more generally, the requirement for additional information is the thing to emphasize: a C-style struct has no extra overhead; when you add virtual functions you've chosen a mechanism that requires additional information, and once you've done that, you also get the information that's needed to support dynamic conversions.

Comment: @PeteBecker sounds strange that dynamic_cast can't figure out whether a Base pointer is pointing to a Base object or a Derived object. There are many ways I can think of... for example decltype(*base_ptr) could tell, or typeid(*base_ptr) ... by dereferecing the pointer you get to the object, and once you have te object, it's easy to come out with its type...

Comment: @gedamial -- no, it's not easy to come out with its type. A `base*` is a pointer to **`base`**. You can't know from its type alone whether the object that it points at is an object of type `base` or an object of some type derived from `base`. So the only thing you can do with it is treat the thing that it points at as an object of type `base`, **unless** you have extra information that **tells you** that it's some other type. The choice in C++ was to not provide that extra information **unless** the class **already has** extra information to support virtual functions.

Comment: If you have access to the pointer, you have access to what it points to. And seems strange you can't know the type of the object pointed at compile time...

Comment: @gedamial -- this is getting far afield for comments on a rather different question. Ask a new question!

Comment: @gedamial consider `Base* bp = (rand() & 1) ? new Base : new Derived;` how could the object type be known at compile time?  RTTI gives you a way to tell the difference at run time, but it imposes an overhead that isn't always necessary.

Comment: @NicolBolas sometimes with templates you don't always know the relationship between two template types.  It's useful to have `dynamic_cast` always work in that situation.